# Can't stop producer/consumer threads with Poison Pill

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, interrupt

I have very simple code which simulates Producer/Consumer stop technique using "Poison Pill".

I have Producer class:

```
public class Producer extends Thread {

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
        while (true) {
                //unblocking this line will cause the code to stop after intrrupt               
                //System.out.println("1");
                queue.put("hello world");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                try {
                    queue.put(Main.POISON_PILL);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Consumer Class:

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String s = queue.take();
                if (s.equals(Main.POISON_PILL))
                    break;
                else
                    System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the main function:

```
public static String POISON_PILL = "POISON_PILL";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } finally {
            producer.interrupt();
        }
    }
```

For not known reason even after `producer.interrupt()` called, 
"hello world" keeps printing in console forever.

Second thing that I can't understand is why uncommenting `System.out.println("1");` will cause program to exit after the producer thread interrupted.

Please help me to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your producer simply runs so much faster than your consumer that you *appear* never to run out of items. Creating a `LinkedBlockingQueue` without an explicit capacity creates one with capacity Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is enough for the consumer to keep printing for quite a while.

That's also probably the reason why it starts working when you add the `System.out.println` line; by requiring console I/O, it slows down the producer to the point where the consumer is able to keep up.

Try creating a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with some small capacity, like 100 or so, instead.

Comment: You could also drain the queue before posting your pill.